# Tumblr Metadata Tags

Tags: metadata, tumblr, meta-tags

Are there metadata tags for sharing content on Tumblr? For example, Facebook uses Open Graph, there are Twitter cards, and Pinterest has Rich Pins. How can I specify the title and subheading that appear when someone shares content from my site on Tumblr?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Tumblr use [Facebook Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me) to scrape pages

[image: Tumblr Link post]
[image: The JSON response from fetch_og]

Things to remember:

- Title is scraped from `<title>`
- Description is scraped from `<meta name="description" content="{content}" />`
- No matter what the size of `og:image` is, Tumblr will resize it and save a `500px` by `500px` image on its servers and use it in `{Thumbnail}` theme operator.
- Tumblr OG scraper gets more than title, description and thumbnail, it gets most of the OG tags so refer to the Documentation of [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me)